# How to Handle Dynamic Conversations in an Aiogram Bot?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Is there a way to make the bot's next question depend on database info and remember the conversation state even after a break?

Any advice or examples would be really helpful!

I'm working on a Telegram bot using Aiogram and need help with managing complex conversations. My bot needs to guide users through different paths based on their answers and information from a database. For example, what the bot asks next might change depending on the user's previous responses and their data stored in the database.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

-Change Conversation Based on User Data
-Remember Where We Left Off
-Handle Long Conversations

I know Aiogram has a state management system, but I'm not sure how to use it for these needs, especially when I have to check the database before deciding what to ask next.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.